# Cancel/Ok missing only on iPhone editor after fire force:editRecord from lightning component running on Napili community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, community, spring16, napili

I am using the following code to edit a record from a lightning component running in Napili community:

```
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": theId
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
```

It works great on my iMac, Mac Air, and iPad but the Cancel and Ok buttons are missing from my iPhone.  Can anyone reproduce or know how to resolve.  One other noteworthy mention is that you couldn't even see the entire form on the iPhone with Winter 16.  It is working way better with Spring 16 except for the missing buttons.